# Построить плотность распределения из дискретных данных (зная гистограмму)

Tags: python, matplotlib, distribution

есть словарь

```
dictionary = {5 : 31, 0 : 29, 12 : 29, 7 : 27, 32 : 26, 13 : 25, 4 : 24, 
              3 : 23, 16 : 23, 17 : 22, 31 : 22, 6 : 21, 9 : 21, 10 : 21,
              2 : 20, 20 : 19, 22 : 19, 23 : 17, 1 : 17, 21 : 17, 
              34 : 17, 24 : 17, 15 : 17, 29 : 16}
```

так можно построить обычную гистограмму по данным значениям (значение - сколько раз это значение встречается)

```
plt.bar(list(dictionary.keys()), dictionary.values(), 1, color='g')
```

Как построить гистограмму распределения значений? (приближающую плотность вероятности распределения) python

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#visualization-kde):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

s = pd.Series(dictionary)

s.plot.kde()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в виде гистограммы:

```
s.plot.hist(alpha=0.6)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сохранить график:

```
plt.savefig(r'/path/to/figure.png')
```